# F#, Performance of sprintf "%A" on Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#

DU have many very useful sides, including built in pretty-printing. However I was surprised that my simple ToString function makes formatting DU more than 1000 times faster. Am I missing something? What is `sprintf "%A"` doing more than my ToString function ?

```
type XYZ = 
    |X of float 
    |Y of float*float 
    |Z

let ar = // some test Array
    [| for i in 1..3000 do for a in [ X(1.) ; Y(2.,3.) ; Z ] do yield a |] 

let xyzToString (x:XYZ) = 
    match x with
    |X (a)  -> sprintf "X %.1f" a
    |Y (a,b)-> sprintf "Y (%.1f,%.1f)" a b       
    |Z      -> "Z"

#time
ar|> Array.map (fun x -> sprintf "%s" (xyzToString x) )  // about   15 ms
ar|> Array.map (fun x -> sprintf "%A" x )                // about 4000 ms
```

Comment: related: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.at/2012/01/fast-generic-pretty-printing.html

Comment: a lot of parsing ... and it's not related to DUs but to the way `sprintf` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mau indicates, your comparison is not apples-to-apples. `printf` accepts arguments *of any type*.  Your function accepts a single known type.

If this becomes a real problem for you, and you are interested in encapsulating the solution a little more cleanly, you can do something like this:

```
type XYZ = 
    |X of float 
    |Y of float*float 
    |Z

    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        |X (a)  -> sprintf "X %.1f" a
        |Y (a,b)-> sprintf "Y (%.1f,%.1f)" a b       
        |Z      -> "Z"

...

ar|> Array.map (fun x -> sprintf "%O" x )
```

Answer (score 5):

`sprintf "%A"` is doing some [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at run time to determine the type and structure of the object being printed, and that's very time consuming.

Your version is bound to a specific type (`XYZ`) at compile time, making it much more efficient.